# LightSwitch - Query based on a SelectedItem from another table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I have two tables, `Customer` and `Address`. One customer can have one or more addresses.

My view is a `ListDetail` with all my customers on the left as a list and the edition on the right.

Under the edition I have the "address area" with a list of addresses and an edition on the selected.

My problem is *all* my addresses are listed. I just want addresses with the matching customerId (selected on the first list).

Here is a drawing to help you see what I am talking about:
[image]

I can create a button on the first list that show a popup with the selected Id but I don't know how to put a parameter on my address collection.

Please tell me if you need more details.

Edit : A good example of what I want is the 'Roles' view created by default. I haven't found how to edit this view to see how it works but if you select a 'role' the list of users is updated to show only those that have this role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your two tables are related (meaning you've created a relationship between them in the table designer), then what you describe should happen automatically. Using the *Add Screen* wizard, you can tick the "related data" checkboxes for any related tables that you want to display for the selected item.

If you didn't tick the checkbox for a table, you can still drag the navigation property (created when you added the relationship), which is on the left side of the screen designer (with a + next to it).

To do it manually, you need to create a *modeled query* (a query based on a table, or on another query), to which you add an *integer* parameter, then add a *filter* based on that parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the related method. It work. I don't understand the second method for doing it manually. Can you explain me more please ?